# How can I redirect to my iPhone web apps from another wep pages?

Tags: iphone, oauth, iphone-web-app

I want to use OAuth in my web apps. I open OAuth page in new window Safari. Can I return to web apps from auth page after authorization?

It's my code for redirect to OAuth page:

```
<a class="auth-link twitter" href="<?php echo (Yii::app()->request->baseUrl); ?>/mobile.html?service=twitter" rel="external" >
<img src="<?php echo (Yii::app()->request->baseUrl); >/img/mobile/soc_icon_tweet.png" id="social_logo" alt="image">
</a>
```

It's impossible?

Comment: Doesn't OAuth automatically redirect back to the page/application?

Comment: OAuth automatically redirect back to the page, but not redirect back to the application. Continue work in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You'll need a native app and then add a custom URL scheme like "oauth://your-url.com".